# How do I sync AWS S3 files using file paths in include option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have following directories structure in my S3 bucket, I want run multiple sync jobs in such a way that I could sync all folders that start with 1 in one job and those which start with 2 in another sync job.

I know I can sync using aws s3 sync s3://bucket my_local_dir for all individual sub-directories.

/Root

- X

  - 1
  - 10
  - 11
  - 114
  - 2
  - 211
  - 213
- Y

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What kind of sync job are you talking about? Where do you want to sync to? One way or two way sync? ...

Comment: Mentioned Directories exist in S3 bucket and I would like to sync them to my local directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- Use `--exclude` to "Exclude all files or objects from the command that matches the specified pattern"`
- Then use `--include` to "Don't exclude files or objects in the command that match the specified pattern"

This seems to work:

```
aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket/ local_dir --exclude "*" --include "1*"
```

Comment: Thanks John, worked as expected for me - checked using `aws s3 --dryrun sync s3://my-bucket/ local_dir --exclude "*" --include "1*" `

Comment: is there a way to sync the specific path, noth the pattern? Because if I use a pattern for 200 files, the sync will be very very slow. If only specific paths are synced and no path matching is needed, the sync will be fast.

Comment: @Ben Please create a new Question with full details of what you are wanting to achieve.